# How to summarize Bridge results?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to summarize Bridge results for each pair (north/south pair and east/west pair).

Match points for pair north/south is `MPNS`, for pair east/west is `MPEW`. Is there a way to summarize all match points for pair from MPNS and MPEW given the following data?

```
Boards results for sample are:
board ns ew score MPNS MPEW
1     1  2  110     0   4
1     3  4  120     2   2
1     5  6  150     4   0
2     1  4  150     4   0
2     2  6  120     2   2
2     3  5  100     0   4
3     1  6  100     1   3
3     4  2  150     4   0
3     5  3  100     1   3

and how get result for pairs:

pair sum
  1     5
  2     6
  3     5
  4     6
  5     9
  6     5
```

Comment: Hi Otm, I've tried to clean up the question, but am still confused on your results. What does 'pair 1' represent, and from your provided results, how is the sum '5' for pair 1?

Comment: sum is sum(MPNS)+sum(MPEW). Pair 1 in this sample all time play on NS and 5 is 0+4+1 Sample of result bridge tournament http://www.bridgekosice.sk/upload/vysledky/n261012.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is one possible solution:

`select a.NS, Sum(a.MPNS) from
(select ns, MPNS from match_points
union all
select ew, MPEW from match_points) a
group by a.ns`

which returns the required results.

SQLFiddle version of the data here - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e473/11